# Xmonad: brightness and file permissions

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to setup my Xmonad to change the back-light intensity on my laptop.

However, to do so, I have to be able to write to the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, which requires the application performing the update to be sudoed (all other suggestions I have tried to use to change the back-light intensity seems to "simulate" it by reducing the brightness of the pixels rather than the back-light).

I've written the necessary code to perform this update and tested it using a sudoed ghci instance, however, when I add this to my Xmonad config, I get a permission denied error.

My question is, what are the usual methodologies for giving window managers extra permissions where required? (I'd ideally not want to change the permissions of this file)

Comment: Using `visudo` to allow your account to execute specific commands should be enough. Cf. the "enable explicitly defined commands" examples [in the relevant Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Example_entries). Alternatively, use a tool that doesn't require elevated permissions, such as [xbacklight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#xbacklight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in in my `sudoers` configuration:

```sh
# /etc/sudoers.d/brightness-mod
```

```sh
ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This allows you to execute, from user mode, commands like

```sh
echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Always use `visudo` to edit sudoers configuration stuff.